# Spiralling Sin Wave Equation

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I am looking to plot a function which has the following shape in python shown in the image below: (apologies for the poor quality). Is there a function that has this form? The only way I can describe it is a sinusoidal spiralling function.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equation on parametric form :

[image]

Comment: WOW. How did you work that out?

Comment: @A-Level Student . Start from parametric equation of ellipse $x=b+r\cos(\omega t)\quad;\quad y=d+\rho\sin(\omega t)$ . Extend the curve horizontally in adding $(at)$ to  $x$. Finally add a sinusoidal term to $y$ in order to create the vertical wave.